# AOP with Autofac and DynamicProxy2

Tags: aop, autofac, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm using Autofac with DynamicProxy2 to intercept my classes like this

```
builder.RegisterType<Calculator>().As<ICalculator>().EnableInterfaceInterceptors()
                .InterceptedBy(typeof (CallLogger));
```

This will intercept all methods on given interface.

Is there any way to intercept only particular methods of the interface ?

Comment: you need to use `IProxyGenerationHook` for that. Not sure if Autofac has a .... hook for this in the API though.

Comment: Please could you provide an example with an IInterceptor derived class ?

Comment: There's an example on my blog, as part of entire tutorial about DynamicProxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways I can think of, and there are probably more out there.

You could create a custom attribute like `[LogCall]` or `[DoNotLogCall]` (opt in or opt out) and apply that to the methods to intercept, then check for the presence of the attribute inside `CallLogger`.

Or, you could configure the `CallLogger` with the names of (or rules to find) the methods that should be logged.